# Custom google map not zooming out

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I've got a custom google map [here](http://www.must.ee/martin_testing/maps_multiple_markers/maptest.html), which has several locations pinned to it.

For some reason the map doesn't zoom out when changing the `zoom` values:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 8,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(59.265881,20.515594),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      mapTypeControl: false,
      streetViewControl: false,
      panControl: false,
      zoomControlOptions: {
         position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_BOTTOM
      }
    });
```

Any ideas what might be causing it?

Rest of the script:

```
var locations = [
      ['html', coordinates],
      ['html', coordinates],
      ['html', coordinates], 
      ['html', coordinates], 
      ['html', coordinates], 
    ];

    // Setup the different icons and shadows
    var iconURLPrefix = 'http://www.bridgingthebaltic.org/wp-content/themes/dante-child/images/';

    var icons = [
      iconURLPrefix + 'map_icon.png',
      iconURLPrefix + 'map_icon.png',
      iconURLPrefix + 'map_icon.png',
      iconURLPrefix + 'map_icon.png',
      iconURLPrefix + 'map_icon.png',
      iconURLPrefix + 'map_icon.png',
    ]
    var icons_length = icons.length;


    var shadow = {
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(15,33),
      url: iconURLPrefix + 'map_icon.png'
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 8,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(59.265881,20.515594),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      mapTypeControl: false,
      streetViewControl: false,
      panControl: false,
      zoomControlOptions: {
         position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_BOTTOM
      }
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      maxWidth: 450
    });

    var marker;
    var markers = new Array();

    var iconCounter = 0;

    // Add the markers and infowindows to the map
    for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map,
        icon : icons[iconCounter],
        shadow: shadow
      });

      markers.push(marker);

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })(marker, i));

      iconCounter++;
      // We only have a limited number of possible icon colors, so we may have to restart the counter
      if(iconCounter >= icons_length){
        iconCounter = 0;
      }
    }



    function AutoCenter() {
      //  Create a new viewpoint bound
      var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
      //  Go through each...
      $.each(markers, function (index, marker) {
        bounds.extend(marker.position);
      });
      //  Fit these bounds to the map
      map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }
    AutoCenter();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For some reason the map doesn't zoom out when changing the zoom values

The reason is this code on your map will cause it to always zoom to fit the bounds calculated:

```
   function AutoCenter() {
      //  Create a new viewpoint bound
      var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
      //  Go through each...
      $.each(markers, function (index, marker) {
        bounds.extend(marker.position);
      });
      //  Fit these bounds to the map
      map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }
```

If you want it to use the zoom set in the map properties, remove the call to that function.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. Removing call to AutoCenter function solved my issue. Next time I'll remind myself to go through the whole code before asking for advice. :)